# Using dates with OR in filtered views

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a filtered view but need to filter columns by OR instead of AND e.g. date in column N is in January 2020 OR the date range in column T is in January 2020 but this doesn't appear to be achievable without an OR custom formula.

Why does the following not work, please: =OR(N:N="date(2020,01)",T:T="date(2020,01)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula does not work because you are comparing dates to string literals, and because the `date()` function requires three arguments.

To more simply compare the year and month, while ignoring the day of the month, use `text()`, like this:

`=or( text(N:N, "yyyy-MM") = "2020-01", text(T:T, "yyyy-MM") = "2020-01" )`

Comment: Thank you doubleunary! How do I incorporate date ranges into this? e.g. 1st Jan - 20th Jan please? Or will this solution not work?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=(N:N=DATE(2021,1,1))+(T:T=DATE(2021,1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you! That's worked for specific dates but not all dates in January. I've removed the day from the end (so 2021,1) but it's not showing any results. Does daterange help with this?